# does Numpy have any dictionary and tuple same as python?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, numpy-ndarray

is there any built-in function in `NumPy` that I can keep both value and array in it? something like
`x = [1,3,[3,4,2],4,[2,6]]`. I try `numpy.array` `append` method but it returns something like `x=[1,3,3,4,2,4,2,6]` is there something like tuple or dictionary or even list in ***Numpy*** that solve my problem ? as I know `ndarrays` of Numpy doesn't works?

please help me with that.

Comment: no, numpy doesn't provide a `dict` or `tuple` type... what exactly are you trying to accomplish, and why does it have to be with `numpy`? The whole *point* of numpy is `numpy.ndarray` ... wht do you mean by "can keep both value and array in it"? Why not just a `list`?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? It is unclear. Maybe you can elaborate on it. Also, numpy has structured arrays that might help your purpose.

Comment: @Ehsan. I want a  NumPy  array-like `x = [1,3,[3,4,2],4,[2,6]] ` you know in the python list there is no problem but I just have a NumPy array

Comment: @masoudanaraki But why do you need an array like that? The answer is yes you can but it is not why you would want to use numpy in the first place. Might as well use lists.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga.
I know that I could use the list but It has to be bumpy 
I mean something like this :
`x = [1,3,[3,4,2],4,[2,6]]`

Comment: @masoudanaraki see if the post answers your question. However, if you explain more on your goal of using it, we might be able to help you better. Thank you

Comment: @Ehsan.
`feature[i,1]=np.mean(I_enh(PixelIdxList[i]))`
in this line of code `I_enh = 300x300 ndarray` and `PixelIdxList` is a list type like x (in last comment) but not exactly same as x , if I want to run this line `PixelIdxList` have to be nd.array

Comment: @masoudanaraki Your comment is still very unclear to me. Maybe you can edit your question to provide a minimal reproducible example, if you would like a more suitable answer. Otherwise, I hope my post solves the issue.

Answer (score 0):

In numpy, you cannot have a non rectangular array of objects. Therefore, you need to store your inner lists as single objects (either list or array).

If you want your elements to be lists:

```
x = np.array([1,3,[3,4,2],4,[2,6]])
#[1 3 list([3, 4, 2]) 4 list([2, 6])]
```

and if you want your elements to be arrays:

```
x = np.array([1,3,np.array([3,4,2]),4,np.array([2,6])])
#[1 3 array([3, 4, 2]) 4 array([2, 6])]
```

However, it is not recommended to use numpy for this kind of data structures unless there is a reason for it.